# VScode failed to run pip install

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, pip, syntax-error

Environment:
Windows10,
Python 3.9.6,
VScode 1.59.0,
No Pylance and Anaconda installation,
I tried to re-installed Python and VScode several times

But when I type
**pip install pandas**
Terminal still shows
**pip install pandas
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Failed to run pip
Really cannot figure this out. Does somebody could give me a hint?

Comment: Please provide the full traceback

Comment: Are you typing this in a python repl? As in first you enter python and then in this interactive repl you run this? Because otherwise, what is telling you invalid syntax? Try running this not in repl.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have the latest version of pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Next, make sure that you are using command prompt or power shell, and not the python interactive window. The reason I say this is because the error you are getting does not usually occur in a normal powershell or command prompt window. This type of error normally only occurs in a python script or in python interactive mode. If you see >>>, it means that you are in the python interactive window.
You can exit it with `exit()` or Ctrl + Z.

If the install still doesn't work, try running pip install by manually opening a powershell or command prompt window outside of vscode.

If you had previously entered a command like `python` or `python3`, you may have entered the python interactive window.

Answer (score 1):

> Terminal still shows

Check if you are writing that in the python interactive window. It shows `>>>`. If you can see that, then exit the window using `exit()` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

Then run

```
pip install pandas
```